# Automatically customizing the front cover of different memoirs

Tags: macros, automation, xstring

I need to create several memoirs with the same format. For each document I want to customize several features of the front cover, for example the background color. I'm trying to automate the customization of the front covers by defining in the preamble of the documents a variable `\doctype` which encodes the document type (let's say type one or type two), and using the `\IfStrEqCase` command to map the document type into the appropriate color. This is my simplified MWE:

**mytemplate.tex**

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

**mycover.tex**

```
\newcommand\CoverBackgroundColor{%
\IfStrEqCase{\doctype}{
    {one}{red}
    {two}{green}
    [gray]
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[\CoverBackgroundColor] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
```

**doc1.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\input{mytemplate}
\newcommand{\doctype}{one}

\begin{document}

\input{mycover}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**doc2.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\input{mytemplate}
\newcommand{\doctype}{two}

\begin{document}

\input{mycover}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I was expecting the front cover of `doc1` to be red and the front cover of `doc2` to be green, but I'm getting this error:

```
<to be read again> 
1
l.9 \fill[\CoverBackgroundColor]
                               (current page.south) rectangle (current page....

?
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Never use `\include` before `\begin{document}`. You definitely want `\input`.

Comment: @egreg Fixed. Thank you for spotting this. Actually I have `\input` in my code as I realized that if I use `\include` the cover page does not get completeley filled with the background color. Any other suggestion regarding my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\CoverBackgroundColor` does *not* expand to a color, but to a set of instructions for *printing* a color name.

Replace the code in `mycover.tex` into

```
%%% mycover.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\CoverBackgroundColor{}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF {\doctype}
   {
    {one}{red}
    {two}{green}
   }
   {gray}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[\CoverBackgroundColor] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
%%%
```

You ***don't*** want to do `\include{mytemplate}`. Use `\input`.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm! In the MWE only the right half of the cover page got colored but in my full code `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` did the trick. Thank you so much!